# Combine array into one string

Tags: python

I want to be able to combine a variable length array into a single string, for example:

```
var1 = ['Hello',' ','World','!']
```

becomes:

```
var2 = 'Hello World!'
```

and the first array may be bigger than 4. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 22):

> [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
>
> Return a string which is the concatenation of the
>   strings in the iterable iterable. The separator between elements is
>   the string providing this method.

List items will be joined (concatenated) with the supplied string. Using `''` will join all items with no character between them.

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> var1 = ['hello', ' ', 'world', '!']
>>> ''.join(var1)
'hello world!'
>>> '     '.join(var1)
'hello           world     !'
>>> '*%*%*'.join(var1)
'hello*%*%* *%*%*world*%*%*!'
>>>
```

Comment: .join is really beautiful.